# How to import a big csv file into database with C# and Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, csv

I am using a basic streamreader to loop through a csv file of about 65gb (450 million rows).

```
using (sr = new StreamReader(currentFileName))
{
    string headerLine = sr.ReadLine(); // skip the headers

    while ((string currentTick = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] tickValue = currentTick.Split(',');
        // Ticks are formatted and added to the array in order to insert them afterwards.
    }
}
```

This creates a list that will hold the ticks that belong to a candle and than call the insertTickBatch function.

```
    private async static Task insertTickBatch(List<Tick> ticks)
    {
        if (ticks != null && ticks.Any())
        {
            using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
            {
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                int currentCandleId = ticks.First().CandleId;
                var candle = db.Candles.Where(c => c.Id == currentCandleId).FirstOrDefault();

                foreach (var curTick in ticks)
                {
                    candle.Ticks.Add(curTick);
                }

                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                db.Dispose();
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
```

This however takes about 15 years to complete and my intention is to speed this up. How do I achieve this?

Comment: well, first step: use an existing CSV-parser instead of simply `Split()`-ing. trust me, it'll save you some troubles down the line.

Comment: That is indeed an imporovement. However, if I run the part of reading the file and creating the models it is done in about 5 minutes. The database part is what makes it slow.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this needs to be done in EF? If you are using MS Sql, then it would be much faster using SQL BulkCopy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which EF you are using, but if available try this instead of your foreach loop:

```
 db.Ticks.AddRange(ticks);
```

Also, CSVHelper is a nice package that can convert your entire file into an Tick object list, and of course the Thread.Sleep has to go.

Comment: The thread sleep allows the garbage collector to clear because otherwise it gives me an out of memory exception. I am not using EF core so i do not have access to AddRange.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it does not look like you need to select Candles at all...try db.Ticks.Addrange(ticks)? Which EF are you using?
As for the garbage collection, that sounds like a threading issue, try locking writes to the db instead, or opening and closing your database context only for the writes :)

Comment: I transfered the project to EF Core which allowed me to use AddRange which sped the process up from 16 years to about 5 hours which is acceptable in this case.

Comment: Great to hear, now you have 15 years and some 12 months to do other things :D If you have the time check Dapper out as an ORM instead of EF as well, it's super fast and flexible for DB operations.

Comment: I will use that spare time to learn as much as possible and will sure check Dapper out, thanks for the response!